# Pandas split string values in column to multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

Yes, I've looked up other questions but I still have trouble getting it right.

I have a df with multiple columns, like this

```
id, hashtag
1234, ['hash1', 'hash2', 'hash3']
1254, [hash1']
1777, ['hash5']
```

I would like the output to have a row for each hashtag and then group the same ones so as to have their frequencies, for instance:

```
hashtag, count
hash1, 2
hash2, 1
hash3, 1
hash5, 1
```

But the output I get has the counts wrong. Here is my code:

```
hashtags_df = df['hashtags'].value_counts().fillna(0).rename_axis('hashtags').reset_index(name='counts')
hashtags_df = df['hashtags'].reset_index(name='index')
hashtags_df['hashtags'] =  hashtags_df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','')) #doing it because it seems like they're not lists. I'm using twint to extract tweets by the way
hashtags_df['hashtags'] = hashtags_df['hashtags'].astype('string') #the dtype otherwise is an obj

hashtags_df.nunique().sum()


new_df = pd.DataFrame(hashtags_df.hashtags.str.split(',').tolist(), index=hashtags_df.counts).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'counts'])
new_df.columns =['counts', 'hashtags']
new_df = new_df['hashtags'].value_counts().rename_axis('hashtags').reset_index(name="counts")

print(new_df)
```

I reworked the code so many times and now it's messed up. It feels like the solution is simple but I can't find it. What should I do?

Comment: This has been asked before probably. If your column's values seem not truly lists but strings, `from ast import literal_eval; df.hashtag.apply(literal_eval).explode().value_counts()` can be tried to turn them to lists first.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function with `value_counts`. No need for anything else.

```
df.hashtag \
  .explode() \
  .value_counts() \
  .reset_index() \
  .rename(columns={"index": "hashtag", "hashtag": "counts"})

  hashtag  counts
0   hash1       2
1   hash5       1
2   hash2       1
3   hash3       1
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because the output still has things like ['hash1', 'hash2', 'hash3', 'hash4']                                                                                             and I need them to be separate

Comment: not sure what you mean, it works fine for me

Comment: It doesn't for me... the column is not type string, I also get the error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hashtags'

Comment: where do you see me write `hashtags`? also I do not treat it as a string, I treat it as a list of lists

Comment: ok, it's cause hashtags was in my example...anyway it doesn't work as a list of lists

Comment: I think before using `explode`, you have to use `from ast import literal_eval; df.hashtag = df.hashtag.apply(literal_eval)`

Comment: if his column is a string type then yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

data = [
    [1234, ['hash1', 'hash2', 'hash3']],
    [1254, ['hash1']],
    [1777, ['hash5']]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["id", "hashtag"])

output = df.explode("hashtag") \
          .groupby("hashtag") \
              .count().reset_index() \
                  .rename(columns={"id": "count"})
```

Output:

```
  hashtag  count
0   hash1      2
1   hash2      1
2   hash3      1
3   hash5      1
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the output is the same as it was before. Strings are not split